Boostrap 5.3 different resolution column doesnt work
I want 4 div's that it must be changed of witdh with different resolutions, but it doesn't work.
I want

when the resolution is ≥992px the div are in the same line (3 column)
when the resolution is ≥768px the divs are in 2 lines, 3 first div in the first line with 4 columns anb the last div in the second with 12 columns
and when the resolution is less the divs must be in 2 lines, the first and second with 6 columns anb the third and foruth the same..

But the last resolution doesn't work, <768. I only see the resolution col-lg and col-md...
But if I delete the resolution col-md, then the resolution col-6 works!
I don't know the answer




<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-danger">Div1 respon</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-primary">Div2 respon</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-success">Div3 respon</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-secondary">Div4 respon</div>
</div>
</body>




You where nearly there. You need to use col-md-12 for the 4th element. You can delete your sm breakpoints as they are redundant. They overwrite your default with the same value.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-danger">Div1 respon</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-primary">Div2 respon</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-success">Div3 respon</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-12 col-lg-3 bg-secondary">Div4 respon</div>
</div>
</body>




No  my code in the stack overflow was incorrected, I put col-md-12 in my case, but the problem is when the device is less <768 the organitzation of the div's doesn-t put col-6, col-6, it doesn't work, it continues with col-md-4..

I can't reproduce that issue with the code provided
